# How to write "AstRoot" object to a file including comments using Rhino?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I've already parsed javascript source using Rhino and reconstructed it successfully.

and when I call ***astroot.toSource()***, it shows to me reconstructed source well.

but ***.toSource()*** method can't prints Comments.

using **.toSource()** method, all my javascript source's comments are disappear.

so, How can I get the full source including comments?

My goal is write AstRoot Object(contain source) to a new javascript file that including full comments.

I'm using Rhino 1.7R4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this is difficult because comments can appear in the middle of any decl, state ment or expression.  So how to represent that fact in the various AST objects?  It could be done but is very messy for parser and the AST objects it creates.

If you restrict yourself to only allowing comments on statement boundaries there are some possible solutions.

One way would be to write your own javascript tokenizer and inspect the stream while reading the file.  Then you would need to figure out how to track them.  One hackish way would be to transform them into 'var somexXXxx = "comment";' and use a naming convention to transform them back after ast.toSource() call.  That would map your comments into the AST node structure.

Comment: thak you for your advise. unfortunately, I cannnot restrict comments. because it already written by other person. inline comments or multiple-line comments are mixed. but I'll try to test like your advise. thanks jarodeells.